# Can RealVNC server on Raspberry be connected from remote using Starlink ISP?

Tags: raspberry-pi, connection, remote-access, vnc

Having RealVNC server on my Raspberry pi, am I able to connect to it via Starlink ISP from a remote site? Starlink uses CG-NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. CG-NAT is a source NAT. You won't be able to do IP source filtering without allowing others on starlink to connect though, so be mindful of your password.